# How to burn a DVD for installing two different Ubuntu Versions

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I would lie to load ubuntu. I Have burned DVD with "Ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386 " and " Xubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386" but unable to install or boot from the DVD do I need to copy Grub along with the *i386 files - please help.

Comment: What system do you have. Almost all systems really should be using the 64 bit version, not the 32 bit version you have. The ISO are complete and boot most systems.  There are a few very lightweight (now older) with 32 bit UEFI, but are 64 bit hardware and do require some work arounds to install a 32 bit UEFI boot loader.

Comment: What did you use to create the DVD?

Comment: When running an operating system (Ubuntu Windows or MacOS) insert the CD and look at it with the file browser. What do you see? One iso file or two iso files (then it is wrong)? Or do you see several directories and files (this looks better)? You should not create a data DVD. You should 'burn an iso file to the DVD disk'. Also please tell us about your computer: Brand name and Model.